# How can I Get Xamarin iOS Application to Automatically Sense Light and Dark Changes?

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvmcross, darkmode

Someone here (thanks sushihangover!) helped me get my application to read the iOS Settings Dark or Light theme on command.  I'm using Xamarin (not Forms). I also need the following (just for iOS):

1. iOS Settings Theme is Light
2. App is set to Automatic, so it uses current the iOS Settings Theme (Light)
3. App launched is Light
4. Home button press
5. Change iOS Settings to Dark
6. Bring app to foreground

App still look Light, but it should look Dark.

I realize the AppDelegate has a WillEnterForeground method, but I don't know how to wire that up so the App looks Dark when it comes to the foreground.  I'm using MvvmCross. The following link looks promising.

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/181648/best-approach-to-handle-dark-theme

I don't understand how to apply the link's contents to my MvvmCross architecture.

Your help is appreciated!

Thanks!
Larry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to react on application changes while using the MVVM pattern would be to implement a `IThemeService` interface as shown in your [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/181648/best-approach-to-handle-dark-theme).

## xamarin forms iOS

But I think it's not possible to react to configuration changes in Xamarin.Forms.iOS plattform while using MvvmCross. I looked into the source code of the [MvvmCross.Forms.iOS](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/MvvmCross.Forms/Platforms/Ios) project and couldn't find any equivalent to the [MvvmCross.Forms.Android](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/MvvmCross.Forms/Platforms/Android) setup methods like `OnConfigurationChanged`.

On Android you can easily refresh the app-theme while change the system theme in the `MainActivity`.

```cs
    public class MainActivity : MvxFormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
        {
            base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
            this.UpdateTheme(newConfig);
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
            UpdateTheme(Resources.Configuration);
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            base.OnStart();
            this.UpdateTheme(Resources.Configuration);
        }

        private void UpdateTheme(Configuration newConfig)
        {
            if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Froyo)
            {
                var uiModeFlags = newConfig.UiMode & UiMode.NightMask;
                switch (uiModeFlags)
                {
                    case UiMode.NightYes:
                        Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IThemeService>().UpdateTheme(BaseTheme.Dark);
                        break;

                    case UiMode.NightNo:
                        Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IThemeService>().UpdateTheme(BaseTheme.Light);
                        break;

                    default:
                        throw new NotSupportedException($"UiMode {uiModeFlags} not supported");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But in the `AppDelegate` on the iOS plattform, you don't have any of these functionalitys to override.

```cs
    public class AppDelegate : MvxFormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
        {
            return base.FinishedLaunching(application, launchOptions);
        }
    }
```

I copied this code from this [project](https://github.com/Baseflow/Chameleon).

## native xamarin iOS

When you are using native iOS you could override the `TraitCollectionDidChange` method. It's the equivalent to the android `OnConfigurationChanged` function.
Maybee look [here](https://intelliabb.com/2019/11/02/how-to-support-dark-mode-in-xamarin-forms/) for more details. I adapted the android version to iOS for you. At First, you have to create a custom view controller.

```cs
// your supported theme versions
 public enum BaseTheme
    {
        Inherit = 0,
        Light = 1,
        Dark = 2
    }

public class MyViewController : UIViewController
    {
        public override void TraitCollectionDidChange(UITraitCollection previousTraitCollection)
        {
            base.TraitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection);

            if (TraitCollection.UserInterfaceStyle != previousTraitCollection.UserInterfaceStyle)
            {
                UpdateTheme(TraitCollection.UserInterfaceStyle);
            }
               
        }

        private void UpdateTheme(UIUserInterfaceStyle newConfig)
        {
            switch(newConfig)
            {
                case UIUserInterfaceStyle.Dark:
                    Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IThemeService>().UpdateTheme(BaseTheme.Dark);
                    break;

                case UIUserInterfaceStyle.Light:
                    Mvx.IoCProvider.Resolve<IThemeService>().UpdateTheme(BaseTheme.Light);
                    break;

                default:
                    throw new NotSupportedException($"UiMode {uiModeFlags} not supported");
            }      
        }
    }
```

I uploaded a project where I simplify coded an implementation for native IOS and android [here](https://github.com/tuke307/Samples/tree/master/Xamarin.MvvmCross.Theme). Complete and improve some things and it will work. Also look at the StarWars and TipCalc Project in the [mvvmcross sample repo](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples).

## mvvmcross ioc

your interface structure could look like so;
IThemeService (base project) - ThemeService (base project) - ThemeService(iOS project)

And you have to register the interface of course.

```cs
Mvx.IoCProvider.RegisterSingleton<IThemeService>(() => new ThemeService());
```

Comment: Hi!  Thanks for your response.  I'm using Xamarin, but not Xamarin Forms.  I'll update the description.  Can your advice be tailored for my architecture?  I can't figure out how.  Thanks!

Comment: I updated the answer, hope you get to the right way.

Comment: I'm working on it now.  If it's not against SO policy, can you shoot an email to lfeldman65@gmail.com or give me your email address?

Comment: I can upload a sample repo on my GitHub  if you want

Comment: That would be great.  Thanks!

Comment: okey i uploaded a simplified sample project; https://github.com/tuke307/Samples/tree/master/Xamarin.MvvmCross.Theme

Comment: Are you available to help with another question via email or video chat?  What's your hourly rate?  Thanks!

Comment: why don't you want to ask a stackoverflow question?

Comment: Some of my questions involve screen sharing and are quite involved.  Please consider.  Thanks!